# Vue.js mounted function runs too early

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Essentially what I am trying to do is to run a a function that adds up different variables and sets a new one its pretty simple:

```
addup: function () {
                        this.homeScore1 = this.m1g1h + this.m1g2h + this.m1g3h + this.m1g4h + this.m2g1h + this.m2g2h + this.m2g3h + this.m2g4h;
                        this.awayScore1 = this.m1g1a + this.m1g2a + this.m1g3a + this.m1g4a + this.m2g1a + this.m2g2a + this.m2g3a + this.m2g4a;
                        this.homeScore2 = this.m3g1h + this.m3g2h + this.m3g3h + this.m3g4h + this.m4g1h + this.m4g2h + this.m4g3h + this.m4g4h;
                        this.awayScore2 = this.m3g1a + this.m3g2a + this.m3g3a + this.m3g4a + this.m4g1a + this.m4g2a + this.m4g3a + this.m4g4a;
                        this.hdoubles = this.m5g1h + this.m5g2h + this.m5g3h + this.m5g4h;
                        this.adoubles = this.m5g1a + this.m5g2a + this.m5g3a + this.m5g4a;
                        alert(this.m1g1h);
                        //total handicap is set here
                        this.hhandicap = this.singlesHHandicap +  this.doublesHHandicap;
                        this.ahandicap = this.singlesAHandicap +  this.doublesAHandicap;

                        //total score is calculated here
                        this.homescore = this.homeScore1 + this.homeScore2 + this.hdoubles + this.hhandicap;
                        this.awayscore = this.awayScore1 + this.awayScore2 + this.adoubles +this.ahandicap;
                    },
```

the value of this.m1g1h for example is set in a function called this.updatesSinglesScores(); that is run on page creation, It calls my databse and assignes the values returned to some vue variables:

```
created: function () {
                    this.updatesSinglesScores();
                    this.updateDoublesScores();
                },
```

afterwards I call the addup function on mounted:

```
mounted: function () {
                    this.addup();
                }
```

So the problem I am having is that the variable this.homeScore1 for example, that is being displayed in the html of the page does not chnages it remains to 0. Upon further inspection with the alert in the addup function I learned that  this.m1g1h remains 0, even though it should be another value. Furthermore if I run the addup function with a button everything works fine. So could some one explain to me why this.m1g1h remains 0? also why does the addup function work when called from a button?

Comment: if updatesSinglesScores calls your database, that means it's an async process that should be managed acordly.

Comment: You might want to make these items `computed`s